Does the first layer of sheathing on 1/0 THHN wire ultimately matter?
This is a question with two parts:
1.) Does it matter mechanically in terms of protecting the wire?
2.) Is it likely a job not pass inspection because of a damaged first layer?
Background:
I'm new to running big wire like this and undersized my first run of conduit between a main panel and subpanel. Pulling the wire through damaged this layer of sheathing at quite a few places. Mind you, the main sheathing is entirely unscathed and in tact. It's just this first thin, glossy layer that sort of packages the rest that's banged up.
See pics below.




Undersized conduit? The inspector is going to make you tear that out.  What size wires in what size conduit?  Crushing as the cost may be, the answer may be to switch to copper conductors, which are generally 2 sizes smaller for the same amps.  I've been forced to do that, on 1000 kcmil wire no less. My wallet still hurts.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica  OP said first run of conduit.  I would assume he learnt a lesson and got bigger conduit for a second run.  OP is asking if the damaged wire is still good to use.  I doubt tape is allowed to cover that size of wire.

Correct. My “first run” was 1 1/4” PVC and getting 3 1/0 THHN copper wires plus the copper ground through there was absolute hell. Definitely a lesson learned. Thankfully this total run is only 10ft so it’s not a massive cost. Tables online tell me 1 1/2 is best but I’m going to 2” just to be safe. Going to replace all the wire too. It’s a $240 cost, but lesson learned.

Also learn the lesson that aluminum is perfectly safe at these large sizes.  However, you're tight but legal at 1-1/4" sch 40 PVC with 36.44% fill on the conductors.  39.79% with #6 copper ground.  Note it could also be a #4 bare ground.  Pulling would be murder, but most first-timers experience that simply because they don't have lube and a truck full of pulling tools.
